# カメラで撮影してサーバーにアップロード

Tags: php, monaca, angularjs

[参考サイト](http://stockcode.info/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA/monaca%E3%81%A7%E5%86%99%E7%9C%9F%E3%82%92%E6%92%AE%E5%BD%B1%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/)を
参考にして、カメラで撮影してサーバーファイルをサーバーにアップロードするアプリと製作しています。
とりあえず、丸々コピーをして動かしてみましたが

error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error...');
の部分でエラーでアップロード出来ていませんでした。
２日ぐらい色々考えたり試したのですが私の今の力では難しいと判断し
質問させていただきます。

alert('error...');を回避してファイルをアップロードできるようにするにはどのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？？

なにぶん、monacaを初めて触るので必要な情報が提示できていないかもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。
必要な情報は教えて頂ければすぐに用意いたします。

**追記

教えて頂いたえらーの表示方法でエラーを表示しました。

200

parsererror

syntaxError: Unexpected token < in

JOSON at position 0

と言うエラーが出ました。**

[image: エラーの詳細を添付します。]

Comment: `alert('error...')` の部分を
 `alert(XMLHttpRequest.status + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown)` に書き換えてから試すとエラーの詳細が出ると思うので、質問下にある[編集]から質問文に追記していただけませんか？

Comment: サーバ側が`<`で始まるテキストを返している(おそらくエラー情報を含むHTML)のでJSONとして解釈できない、と言う状態ですね。unaristさんの示されたコードの`XMLHttpRequest.status`の部分を`XMLHttpRequest.responseText`に置き換えて何か情報は得られないでしょうか。

Comment: unarist様、OOPer様ありがとうございます。
原因がわかりました！！
保存場所のフォルダのパーミッションが書き込めなかったのでエラーになっていました。
皆さんの協力でエラーの出し方も解り勉強になりました。

ありがとうございます。